# psexec exit with process id in jenkins

Tags: batch-file, jenkins, psexec

In Jenkins, while using `psexec`  to run a batch file

```
psexec \\workstation007 -u user -p Pa55w0rd -accepteula -i 2 -h cmd.exe /k "abc.bat"
```

starts a new prompt in remote machine and loops in spinner rotating in console log

```
psexec \\workstation007 -u user -p Pa55w0rd -accepteula -i 2 -h -d cmd.exe /k "abc.bat"
```

starts new prompt but exits with process id in console log.

But I want to display everything that is displayed on cmd prompt in the console log itself.
The batch file has other commands for execution. I assume that as the commands are not completely executed, the -d wont wait for process to complete,so it returns the process id. How should I handle this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With much of R&D,

The solution for this was `paexec`. While `psexec` supported 80 characters, the functional clone `paexec` supported whole of it.
Syntax I used:

```
paexec \\remote_machine -u user -p password /accepteula -h cmd /c "D:\abc.bat" arg1 arg2
```